# Is there a way to globally specify where Unison should log?

Tags: linux, logging, unison

I'd really like to have Unison log only to a specific file for ALL of my profiles. I have a number of different profiles, 3 local ones, and one remote one (my laptop syncs with this computer to keep up to date on music). Is there a way to set the log location for all of these? I know I can specify the log location within each profile file, but what about the remote sync? How can I specify where log output goes? (It currently goes to `/home/$USER/unison.log` which is really annoying).

Comment: Maybe the -logfile option is what you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. I can't find anything on the subject across the web and believe me, I've looked.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this question, it is possible now. Not via command line arguments as far as I can tell, but you can set the `UNISON` environment variable to provide a custom location for the `.unison` folder where the logs are place. (Note that this folder probably doesn't even have to be called `.unison`, but I only tested it like that).

```
$ export UNISON=/my/custom/.unison
$ unison -auto ~/music /webshare/music
```

**Source:** [unison 2.9.1 manual](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/unison-2.9.1/unison-manual.pdf)